# Read/write a PDF file using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I have an editable PDF File, I am rendering that PDF File in my Web Page using HTML 5 Object element(Tag). Now I am doing some changes in that PDF File and after that I am trying to save that PDF file with a download option. But I am not able to download the updated(After Changes) PDF File. I am getting the initial loaded PDF File.

But I am trying to download after changes PDF File. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I approve of the edit by Marc-Antoine.

Comment: Did you read the answer to this question: [How to edit a PDF embedded in the browser and save the PDF directly to server?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-edit-pdf-embedded-browser-and-save-pdf-directly-server) Note that most PDF viewers don't support what you are trying to achieve. I fail to see why you think this is an iText question, let alone an iText problem.

Comment: I am trying to save the editable PDF file from web browser using HTML5 and java script without server interaction. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: Your requirement is not supported by any tool I know.